# how to add click event on array values and change the textbox values?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to add a click event to every similar artist. If the user clicks on a similar artist, that artist name is placed in the textbox and the page acts as if the button has been pressed. Every button press will just provide the "hard coded" information about James Taylor. So, when the user clicks on one of the similar artists, I have to invoke a function that puts the similar artist's name in the text box and it should then pop up an alert that says "AJAX call being made for artist: " + artistName.

When I click on an artist name, all the artists names show up again instead and the value in the textbox says `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Musician Biography (ajax demo)</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #607070;
                color:white;
                font-size:14px;
                font-weight:bold;
                letter-spacing:1px;
                line-height:24px;
                margin:auto;
                font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            }
            #box, table {
                margin:15px;
            }
            .pic {
                border: 5px inset white;
                padding: 10px;
                margin:15px;
            }
            .none {
                display:none;
            }
            #similarArtistsDivId {
                margin-left: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>This version "hard codes" a call to a saved local text file 
            that contains the JSON - this is so my Web API key doesn't lock out from overuse</h4>
        <div id="box">
            <h1>Get Bio (AJAX demo) Plain JavaScript</h1>
            <h2> -> hard coded for James Taylor</h2>
            <form name="music">
                Enter the name of your favorite artist, for example
                <input id= "textBoxId" type="text" name="artist" value="" size="30" />
                <input type="button" value="Get Bio" onClick="sendRequest(document.music.artist.value)"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="picture" src="" alt=""></td>
                <td id="bio"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="similarArtistsDivId"></div>
        <script>

            //Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
            //alert('create req');
            var httpReq;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                httpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");         //For IE 5+
            } else {
                alert('ajax not supported');
            }

            function sendRequest(artist) {

                var call = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist="
                        + artist +
                        "&api_key=....&format=json";

                // Don't make a live call (dont want the Web API key to get shut 
                // down with everyone running in lab.
                call = "03b_last_fm_json.txt";  // call pre-saved AJAX response

                //alert ('sending request with URL '+call);

                httpReq.open("GET", call);
                httpReq.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
                httpReq.send(null);
            }

            function handleResponse() {
                //alert('handling response');
                if (httpReq.readyState === 4 && httpReq.status === 200) {

                    var response = httpReq.responseText;
                    //alert ("response text is " + response);

                    // wrap the json in parentheses to avoid tripping over javascript ambiguity...
                    response = "(" + response + ")";
                    var jsonObj = eval(response);
                    //alert ("artist is "+jsonObj.artist);

                    if ((jsonObj.artist === null) || (jsonObj.artist.similar.artist === null)) { // means artist not found.
                        document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = "<br/><br/>" + jsonObj.message;
                        document.getElementById("picture").src = "";
                        document.getElementById("picture").setAttribute("class", "none");
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = jsonObj.artist.bio.summary;
                        //alert ("image link is" + jsonObj.artist.image[4]['#text']);
                        document.getElementById("picture").src = jsonObj.artist.image[3]['#text'];
                        document.getElementById("picture").setAttribute("class", "pic");

                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.artist.similar.artist.length; i++) {
                            var similarArtist = document.createElement("div");
                            similarArtist.innerHTML = jsonObj.artist.similar.artist[i].name;

                            document.getElementById('similarArtistsDivId').appendChild(similarArtist);
                            similarArtist.onclick = function() {
                                sendRequest(this);
                                document.getElementById('textBoxId').value = textBoxId;   
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close

```
similarArtist.onclick = function() { 
  var artist =  this.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('textBoxId').value=artist;
  sendRequest(artist);
};
```

Also please give the form an ID of music, change the button to type="submit" and add this script so you can hit enter in the form (and remove the script from the button)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("music").onsubmit=function() {
    sendRequest(this.artist.value);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: omg.. thank you! But my list still repeats the whole list of names when I click on one name.

Comment: What does that mean? If I clicked Cher, I got Kylie Minogue - Cher should then be in her list

Comment: I have a txt file with all the artists names and when I click on a name from the list of names, the whole list of names shows up again below the original list of names. https://imgur.com/QpinfTd

Comment: It is because the similar artist is the same for all the artists who are similar.

Comment: Please see update for an additional improvement. Also change the call to https://ws.audioscrobbler.com